# Does the Source Control Feature have an option to include whitespace in template?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the latest update of Visual Studio Code, I noticed that the source control git message feature started ignoring white space in my git template. **Is there a way to revert to previous behavior?**

#### Further Detail

In the past for git, I had a template commit message file similar to the following:

```
#

# Various Billing codes: I'd un-comment the one I need at the time
# Billed to Project 1
Billed to Project 2
#Billed to Project 3
```

With this, I would simply type my subject in place of the pound and continue from there. Visual studio Code used to include the two initial white spaces in its message box. I'd get this:

```
_

Billed to Project 2
```

Where the underscore is where I begin typing. Now it is simply:

```
Billed to Project 2
```

This is particularly frustrating since the billing codes exceed the 50 character subject limit, and it wants to display its warning each time. I personally like the 50 character subject limit and a 78 character line limit, so I don't want to disable that feature. And, I can't change the billing code as it is company standard. Any thoughts into getting my precious white spaces back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71312). It should be fixed in VS Code 1.38+